# Is voltage an electromagnetic signal?

Tags: electromagnetic

I am currently studying data communications, and I read somewhere that data is represented as an electromagnetic signal such as voltage, microwave and radio wave. Now I know electromagnetic radiation is a range of different wavelengths with different properties which radio waves and microwaves are part of, but I did not think electrical voltages was an EM wave, so I don't understand this sentence.

Comment: The word "signal" is very ambiguous in this context so the answers you get may use different terminology. Also, _voltage_ is the difference in the energy in charges measured between two different points. A voltage that is _time varying_ can produce an electromagnetic wave, but a constant voltage only produces an EM field.

Answer (score 3):

It's a *field* rather than a *wave*, where EM waves are changes in the local EM fields. The classic [diagram](http://www.wikipremed.com/01physicscards.php?card=810) shows the relation of a wave to the two types of field, electrical and magnetic.

Wherever there is a voltage between two points, there will be an electrical field between those two points. If there is a current flowing along a wire, there will be a magnetic field *around* the wire.

Some devices rely on electric fields for their operation, notably the *field*-effect transistor, but also the thermionic valve where the field controls electron flow between two plates in a vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

An electro motive force is measured in volts and is commonly called "voltage". A magneto motive force is measured in ampere-turns and is commonly called current.

The two together constitute an electromagnetic  field but seperately they are not. An EM signal could be describing an EM field or radio wave or beam of light for that matter.